# Windows 7: A drive became as free space

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, partitioning

Today I came across a strange problem! I have 3 partition in my **500 GB HDD**:

- **C:** OS drive - 145 GB
- **E:** Local Disk - 133 GB
- **G:** Local Disk - 186 GB
  Today after usual windows updates:
  [image: Update window 1]

[image: Update window 2]

And after restarting my laptop, **I lost my G drive!**!!!!!!!!!!! When I checked disk management it says: free space 186 GB

[image: Disk Management]

Can anyone give me a solution for this. I have data in my G drive but unfortunately I don't have backup of the drive!!

Comment: After you take an image of the HDD, you should use the application of choice, and attempt to restore the partition table on the drive. You should also take immediate actions to replace the drive.  Recovery of the partition you lost is not guaranteed.  You should assume the updates and restart had nothing to do with the lost of the drive, it's very likely, even though the volume was mounted the data wasn't accessible even before the reboot (personal experience tells me this it the case)

Comment: If the data is critical, I suggest professional recovery before tinkering with it on your own. This company helped me by recovering 1tb of data after the partition was corrupted....http://www.lowcostrecovery.com/

Comment: @Ramhound But what exactly is the reason for this? I mean i dint install any 3rd party tools nor I had any OS crash!

Comment: @Moab Thank you for the suggestion. Well actually its the company's laptop & I din't have informed as I don't want to be blamed so I wanna try any possible recovery on my own first.

Comment: If it's your company laptop, time to allow the Administrator, figure out a solution.  You shouldn't be attempting ANY solution.  Since we are talking about company property, and I am an Administrator and would be frustrated by any user who attempted data recover on property I was in charge of, I cannot in good faith answer any of your questions.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks bro. I think that would be a better thing to handover the laptop to the Admin. But still I would like to know the reason for the volume disappearing.